# Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target in Angular2 MEAN app

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I dont understand whats unique here. I am trying to simply load all of the objects of a class called asset, but I keep getting this error when I try to save the results.

***asset.service.ts (24, 23): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target***

I have the following code

**assets.component.ts**

```
export class AssetsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private assetService: AssetService, private errorService: ErrorService) { }

  assets: Asset[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.assetService.getAssets()
      .subscribe(
        assets => {
          console.log('assets is', assets);
          this.assets = assets;
          this.assetService.assets = assets;
        },
        error => this.errorService.handleError(error)
      )
  }

}
```

**asset.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AssetService {
  @Output() asset: Asset;
  assets: Asset[] = [];

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getAssets() {
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/asset')
      .map(response => {
        const data = response.json().obj;
        console.log('getAssets data from response is');
        console.log(data);
        let objs: any[] = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          console.log('Asset Data here is', data[i]);
          let asset = new Asset(data[i].name, data[i].mimetype, data[i].filename, data[i].local_path, data[i].size);
          objs.push(asset);
        }
        return objs;
      })
      .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.json()));
  }

}
```

and in my **assets.js** routes (in node using express) I have

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Asset.find()
    //.populate('name', 'filename')
    .exec(function(err, docs) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          title: 'An Error occured',
          error: err
        });
      }
      console.log('node get docs are');
      console.log(docs);
      res.status(200).json({
        asset: 'Success',
        obj: docs
      });
    });
});
```

my asset.ts model in Angular2 looks like:

```
export class Asset {
  name: string;
  mimetype: string;
  filename: string;
  local_path: string;
  size: number;
  s3loc: string;
  thumb_local_path: string;
  proxy_local_path: string;
  thumb_s3_path: string;
  proxy_s3_path: string;

... constructor follows...
```

Answer (score 0):

So this turned out to be something simple as expected, but I didnt see this answer when searching. Even though I know when this specific getAssets call is run, it usually will not have all of the fields come back in the response, for this to work, All fields **must** be accounted for in the new Asset section for the object being created in the asset service.

so the line above:

```
let asset = new Asset(data[i].name, data[i].mimetype, data[i].filename, data[i].local_path, data[i].size);
```

Must actually be

```
let asset = new Asset(data[i].name, data[i].mimetype, data[i].filename, data[i].local_path, data[i].size, data[i].s3loc, data[i].thumb_local_path, data[i].proxy_local_path, data[i].thumb_s3_path, data[i].proxy_s3_path);
```